# installation procedure by wubi

Tags: installation, wubi

I have installed  ubuntu 12.04 on my machine by wubi software.
During installation procedure, install stop/pause or take too much time(45 min.) to install and stuck at that point.If I restart machine then after showing some error ubuntu get started and work fine ...
  If its the way to install ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

installing ubuntu using wubi is fine, if you are a rookie and dont want mess up the partitions. But the best way to install ubuntu is by booting from the CD/USB and install it to the hard drive. as described [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-install.html)